# Can I easily "eject" an installed Bit component into the local project to remove the package dependancy?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bit.dev

We have a couple of use cases here and there where we are using Bit to pass around our React components we use a lot in our projects. Occasionally we need to hand off the code base to the client per the contract and because we like to keep our internal components private from bit and GitHub if the person we hand the project to isn't added into our bit organization they can't install the components we have added in our `package.json` that is hosted in Bit.

So far I can't find a place in the docs that outlines how I might "eject", to use a CRA term, the component out of `node_modules` and into the local project files and then remove the `package.json` dependency so we can use our components installed from Bit but then later remove the need to have these installed from Bit during a handoff by having them embedded directly int he project.

The thought is that because projects are not always set up the same from developer to developer that Bit doesn't have something like this, in which case we'll have to set up our own script to handle this but I figured I would reach out to anyone who may have used Bit before to see if anyone knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using `bit import` to import the components before you send the app to your client.
After you imported the components they will be in a dedicated folder, "components" folder by default, and all the dependencies in the `package.json` file will be updated to point to the "components" folder.
You can read more about importing components here:
https://docs.bit.dev/docs/sourcing-components

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, just didn't know how to find in their docs what I was looking for